# getting length cannot be less than zero parameter name length in exe mode

Tags: c#, winforms

Update: This is the code

```
string path = Application.StartupPath.Substring(0, Application.StartupPath.LastIndexOf("bin"));
```

Exception text:

```
Length cannot be less than zero
Parameter name :  length

See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Length cannot be less than zero.
Parameter name: length
   at System.String.InternalSubStringWithChecks(Int32 startIndex, Int32 length, Boolean fAlwaysCopy)
   at System.String.Substring(Int32 startIndex, Int32 length)
   at Negits_POS.frmItemEdit..ctor(String Strmode, String StrItemId)
   at Negits_POS.frmItemDetails.btnEdit_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at Negits_POS.frmItemDetails.dgItem_CellMouseDoubleClick_1(Object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnCellMouseDoubleClick(DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnMouseDoubleClick(MouseEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)


************** Loaded Assemblies **************
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
Negits_POS
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Microsoft/PS/Negits_POS.exe
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1 built by: RTMRel
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1 built by: RTMRel
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
System
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1 built by: RTMRel
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
Negits_DAL
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Microsoft/PS/Negits_DAL.DLL
----------------------------------------
Negits_LIB
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Microsoft/PS/Negits_LIB.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.Configuration
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xml
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version`enter code here`n: 4.0.30319.1 built by: RTMRel
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Data
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/System.Data/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Core
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1 built by: RTMRel
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Core/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll
----------------------------------------
MySql.Data
    Assembly Version: 6.8.3.0
    Win32 Version: 6.8.3.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/MySql.Data/v4.0_6.8.3.0__c5687fc88969c44d/MySql.Data.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Transactions
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/System.Transactions/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Transactions.dll
----------------------------------------
System.EnterpriseServices
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/System.EnterpriseServices/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.EnterpriseServices.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Management`enter code here`
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Management/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Management.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Numerics
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1 built by: RTMRel
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Numerics/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Numerics.dll
----------------------------------------
RabbitMQ.Client
    Assembly Version: 3.2.3.0
    Win32 Version: 3.2.3.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/RabbitMQ.Client/3.2.3.0__89e7d7c5feba84ce/RabbitMQ.Client.dll
----------------------------------------

************** JIT Debugging **************
To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this
application or computer (machine.config) must have the
jitDebugging value set in the system.windows.forms section.
The application must also be compiled with debugging
enabled.

For example:

<configuration>
    <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
</configuration>


    When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception
    will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer
    rather than be handled by this dialog box.
```

The following error occurs only when application is run from exe file. When it runs in debug mode it does not throw the exception. How to get rid of this error? The error occurs only when user clicks the menu item representing the option to upload image.

Comment: Especially `Negits_POS.frmItemEdit.ctor(String Strmode, String StrItemId)`, because it seems, that this is the method, which causes the problem.

Comment: The error means that you provide a less than zero length to the Substring method. This might vary depending on the data you use hence the difference between debugging and running the exe. If you use the same data, it is very likely that you can reproduce the error. A good first step would be to locate calls to Substring in the constructor and check, which input data could lead to a less than zero length. Look especially for calculations or the result of IndexOf.

Comment: string path = Application.StartupPath.Substring(0, Application.StartupPath.LastIndexOf("bin"));
Eror is thrown in this line

Comment: Actually what path you need to refer? You need your project path? It doesn't makes sense to find project path when exe is depoyed

Comment: If it runs in debug mode then the exe will be inside a bin directory.  In executable mode it probably wont.

Comment: i need the path of the image where it is stored

Comment: If your application is running in end user's machine where those images will be?

Comment: it is stored in a folder sepeartely and also in db

Comment: i have the same error but different code. my problem is aswell: the exception doesn't get thrown when i debug the project. but if someone calls my wcf service from infoPath it will show this error for them.

Answer (score 1):

you have to check the path of your exe if `bin` exist

```
string path;
if(Application.StartupPath.LastIndexOf("bin") >0)
   string path = Application.StartupPath.Substring(0, Application.StartupPath.LastIndexOf("bin"));
else
{
  string path = string.Empty
  MessageBox("Check your path : " +   Application.StartupPath);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you get this issue in iis server configuation do the simple thing change the connection string in  web.config file  like your sql server name and server name and restart iis then try to load the page it works