# How to convert string to image?

Tags: c#, .net, string, image

```
private void btnread_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(MyConnectionString);
    connection.Open();
    MySqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT imagecol FROM imgtable WHERE id = 17";
    MySqlDataAdapter adap = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);`enter code here`
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    adap.Fill(dt);
    string b = dt.Rows[0]["imagecol"].ToString();
    byte[] storedImage = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(b);
    byte[] ss = (byte[])dt.Rows[0]["imagecol"];
    Image newImage;
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(storedImage))
    {
        newImage = Image.FromStream(stream);
    }

    //// Display to make sure code works
    picbox.Image = newImage;
    connection.Close();
}
```

Comment: the following code throws error in the following line (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(storedImage)) newImage = Image.FromStream(stream); } error:invalid parameter

Comment: What is the datatype of `imagecol` in Database?

Comment: Your `byte[] <--> string` conversion is wrong. Don't do it. See this for example `var buf1 = new byte[]{165,166,167}; 
            var buf2 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buf1));` Output will be `63,63,63`, not the original bytes.

Comment: longblob is the datatype

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to convert to `byte[]` to `string` then back to `byte[]` using `ASCII.GetBytes`.

This should solve your problem.

```
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(ss))
{
    newImage = Image.FromStream(stream);
}
```

Side note: Give proper names for members even when you write a sample application. `ss` is not meaningful.

Comment: I would be delightful if i can up vote the **side note** too.

Comment: if i do like this its throwing error as "invalid parameter" for stream in newImage = Image.FromStream(stream);

Comment: It raises the question whether it is a valid image?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel,  user3349540, `storedImage` contains **invalid data** because you can not get a byte array from a string that way. See my example in the comments.

Comment: @L.B I know that's wrong so that I used `new MemoryStream(ss)` where ss is the actual bytes from DB. column is already `byte[]` converting it to string and bytes is not what he needs. Am I correct?

Comment: string path = Application.StartupPath.Substring(0, Application.StartupPath.LastIndexOf("bin")); kindly let me know any alternate to this line can be use.This line is working proper when we execute in debug mode but when an exe application is created its throwing error.why is it so?

Comment: What you're tring to get with that code? You can use `Directory.GetParent` for this purpose. Or you better ask a new question if you need

Comment: have used that code to get the path of image stored in db

Comment: kindly check the following linkhttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/22033270/getting-length-cannot-be-less-than-zero-parameter-name-length-in-exe-mode?noredirect=1#comment33403321_22033270